# Google cloud platform setup ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ml) Invalid choice: 'init-project'

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I am using cloud shell in google cloud platform. I am trying to getting things installed for machine learning. The codes that I have used so far are

```
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-ml/scripts/setup_cloud_shell.sh | bash
export PATH=${HOME}/.local/bin:${PATH}
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-ml/scripts/check_environment.py | python
gcloud beta ml init-project
```

It works fine in the first three lines but for the last command, I get

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ml) Invalid choice: 'init-project'.
Usage: gcloud beta ml [optional flags] <group>
  group may be           language | speech | video | vision 
For detailed information on this command and its flags, run:
  gcloud beta ml --help
```

this error for the last gcloud~ line. Anyone knows what I can do to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ml) Invalid choice: 'init-project'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608587/error-gcloud-beta-ml-invalid-choice-init-project)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to delete my previous question. I did not get answers so I posted another using different tags.

Comment: You should just edit tags in the old question, and not post a new one.

Comment: Sorry, should have done that :-(

Comment: Now you know for the next time :) BTW, the command `gcloud beta ml` only accepts [one of the following flags](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/ml/): `language`, `speech`, `video` or `vision.` You cannot use `'init-project'`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I.e. what are you using that command for?

Comment: I am using tensorflow to do machine learning but it is taking way to much time on my laptop. So I am trying out google cloud platform and youtube tutorial told me to use following codes on the console. I am not sure of the exact meaning though :-( I just need machine learning to deal with economic data but this is way more difficult than I had imagined

Comment: I'd suggest that you follow the official documentation for Cloud ML Engine. There are many tutorials and guides available, and they will teach you how to train models, deploy already trained models, and get predictions in the cloud. You can start from this page, which explains [how to train a model in the Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/training-steps), and then go to the other documentation pages that you need.

Comment: Thank you! I will try my best! :-)

Answer (score 1):

First off, let me note that you don't need to run the BETA command as the [gcloud ml](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml/) variant is also available.

As the error message indicates, 'init-project' is not a valid choice, you should instead use one of the following groups: [language](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/), [speech](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/), [video](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/), [vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/), each of which allows you to make calls to the corresponding API. For instance, you could run the following:

```
$gcloud ml vision detect-faces IMAGE_PATH
```

and detect faces within the indicated image.

That said, from your comments it appears that you are not interested in any of the above. If you are looking to train your own TensorFlow models on google cloud platform, you should take a look at the docs relating to Cloud ML Engine. The page that [dsesto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4482491/dsesto) pointed you to is a good start. I would advise that you also try out the examples in this [github repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples), particularly the [census](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census) one. Once there, you'll also see that the gcloud command group used for training models on the cloud (as well as deploying them and using them for prediction jobs) is actually [`gcloud ml-engine`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml-engine/), not gcloud ml.